# What are all the new coins listed on the trading market & what value do they represent? what are their uses?

Tags: currencies

Just scrolled over all the different coins to trade I couldn't beleive how many there is, what are there uses, and is it something that is easy to set up?

Comment: All scams. None.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. It depends on your view on altcoins, as @Jannes has so kindly demonstrated.

These are altcoins, built off the bitcoin protocol as an **alt**ernative to bit**coin**. If you want, you can invest into them. But please, do your research on that coin. Altcoins have a notorious history of devs mining large amounts of coins before the coin is released, and then when the coin gets a bit of interest from the community and a higher price, devs just sell everything.

Some coins are scams, some very well may be, and some are actually pretty good projects and have a large userbase. Namely Litecoin and Ethereum.